# can we do weighted routing on s3 endpoints?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

Hi everyone I have two s3 endpoints and I have a domain name I want to point both s3 endpoints to my domain name and do a weighted policy of 50% to one s3 endpoint and 50% to another is this possible in Aws can I do this? For this, we have to create two buckets with the same name and that's not possible am I right here?

Comment: You can't create two S3 buckets with the same name. They must be globally unique. What is the real underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I deployed two versions of my website to AWS s3 and with the two endpoints I want to do a weighted policy in route53

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60030262/s3-static-website-w-bluegreen-deployment